# How to start an EXE which expects a config file in current directory being the EXE directory from a different directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, executable

I'm trying to launch an executable through a batch script. But my problem is that the executable requires a config file in the same directory as itself and instead it seems like the path to the batch file gets set to the current directory. So the executable looks for the configuration file in the batch's directory instead of it's own.

So far I've tried:

```
cd \\server\path\dir
programToRun.exe
```

and

```
start \\server\path\dir\programToRun.exe
```

but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

From my one contribution to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut

UNC default paths are turned off by default as they used to crash older programs.[10]

The Dword registry value `DisableUNCCheck` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`[10] allows the default directory to be UNC. `CD` command will refuse to change but placing a UNC path in Default Directory in a shortcut to Cmd or by using the Start command. `start "" /d \\127.0.0.1\C$ "cmd /k"` (C$ share is for administrators).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help but I was able to fix it by editing the C# code behind the executable.

I swapped out Directory.getCurrentDirectory() with System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace("programToRun.exe", null)